# How to add variable to list from different class

Tags: c#

I am creating app with data base inside in windows forms and i don't know how to pass information through one class to another like here:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            BazaDanychTabela BazaDanychTabelaVariable = new BazaDanychTabela();
            string rejestracja = Rejestracja.ToString();

            var dataoddania = dateTimePicker1.Value;
            var kosztczescizamiennych = numericUpDown2.Value;
            var pracamechanikawgodzinach = numericUpDown1.Value;

            var index = MechanicyBox.SelectedIndex;

            if (index < 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Prosze Wybrac Mechanika");
            }
            else
            {
                var imie = ListC[index].Name;
                var nazwisko = ListC[index].Nazwisko;

                // this one I want to add
                BazaDanych NowyLog = new BazaDanych(imie, nazwisko, rejestracja, dataoddania, kosztczescizamiennych, pracamechanikawgodzinach);  
                MessageBox.Show("Nowy log zostal utworzony!");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the other class:

```
public partial class BazaDanychTabela : Form
{
    public List<BazaDanych> Logi  = new List<BazaDanych>();
}
```

And I want to add "NowyLog" to "Logi" how?

Comment: `BazaDanychTabelaVariable.Logi.Add(NowyLog);`

Comment: Ty @Orion have a greate day :3